Understanding minikube volume created on docker with minikube start
I am running minikube with help of Docker Desktop on an M3 MacBook Pro.
If I specify the env variable MINIKUBE_HOME like so:
export MINIKUBE_HOME=/path/to/minikube
minikube start
...
minikube v1.34.0 on Darwin 15.0.1 (arm64)
▪ MINIKUBE_HOME=/path/to/minikube

I see that it gets populated with various files and folders during setup.
However a volume named 'minikube' gets created within Docker as well with a well defined structure that I am not listing :
/backup
/cache
/opt
other folders...

I wanted to know the difference between these two kind of folders (MINIKUBE_HOME and minikube under docker volumes) and hopefully if there's a way to have all these 'systems' folders created under a common path of choice.
